# issue in deleting last element of vector in a loop

Tags: c++11, vector, stl, runtime, erase

In the below code if I try to remove any element except last one the code works fine . But if I try to delete last element it throws run time error . Not sure why ?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    vector<string> s;
    s.push_back("Jacob");
    s.push_back("Jamal");
    s.push_back("Joseph");
    s.push_back("Janardan");
    vector<string>::iterator it;

    for(it = s.begin(); it != s.end() ; it++)
        cout<<*it<<endl;

    for(it = s.begin(); it != s.end() ; it++)
        if(*it == "Janardan")
           s.erase(it);  

    for(it = s.begin(); it != s.end() ; it++)
        cout<<*it<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The reason it throws a runtime error is because you are trying to increment the iterator by calling `it++` after you have deleted the last element. This results in iterator going out of range. A better way to solve this would be:

```
for(it = s.begin(); it != s.end();) {
    if(*it == "Janardan") {
       it = s.erase(it);  
    } else {
       it++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are 4 elements in the your `std::vector`, so the loop will execute 4 times.

The problem is, when you delete an element, all iterators **after** the deleted elements are no longer valid. That includes `it`, which points to an element which no longer exists, and so it will throw.

---

There are many solutions you can use

- If the `std::vector` doesn't have any duplicates, you could `break` after erasing an element
- Use `std::remove_if`

Like so

```
std::remove_if(std::begin(s), std::end(s), [](const auto& value) {
    return value == "Janardan";
});
```

- Use `std::find`

Like so

```
auto iterator = std::begin(s); //Initialize iterator to the first element

//std::find returns std::end(s) if it didn't find anything
if ((iterator = std::find(std::begin(s), std::end(s), "Janardan")) != std::end(s))
    s.erase(iterator); //Erase element
```